# Call action method in jQuery with Kohana php framework

Tags: php, jquery, kohana-3

In Asp.Net MVC I have used helpers to specify paths to actions and controllers, like this:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("OrderAction", "OrderController")";
$.post(url, { name: name, prodno: prodno }, function(data) {
    //Do stuff    
});
```

Now I'm trying to learn Kohana and php, and I was wondering if there is a similar way to do it there? Or how else do I call a specific action method in a controller to post to it?

EDIT: Here's the routing in bootstrap.php if it helps:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Reverse Routing](http://www.kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=routing%3areverse_routing_and_pagination) to transform a route and optional arguments to the link...

```
echo Route::url('route_name', array('optional' => 'arguments'));
```

> ...could you provide an example of how I would use this to produce the call to OrderAction method in OrderController controller[?]

```
echo Route::url('default',
                 array('controller' => 'Order', 'action' => 'Action')
               );
```

Comment: Ok... This looks very complicated compared to the Url.Action helper... Excuse me for my rudimentary understanding of Kohana so far, but could you provide an example of how I would use this to produce the call to OrderAction method in OrderController controller as in my example?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried it though, and it produced this url: href="http://localhost/kohana/index.php/home/order. Here's what I put in the variable, I assume that is how you meant: var url = "<?php echo Route::url('default',
                 array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'order')
               ); ?>"; (I.e. home is the name of the controller, and order is the name of the action, the others were just to clarify my question)

Comment: So obviously, that's not going to work. Where does the index.php come from here?

Comment: @Anders Open `application/bootstrap.php` and set `Kohana::init(array(
'index_file' => FALSE));`

Comment: Ok, did that, and it got rid of the index.php, but it still doesn't call the action. The url the above produces now is: localhost/kohana/home/order. My views are in kohana/application/views, I assume the routing should still redirect it there? I'll include my routing in an edit to the question!

Comment: @Anders The route should only know about controllers, never models or views. Are you new to the MVC paradigm ?

Comment: well, not exactly, but I guess I haven't had to worry much about routing in Asp.Net MVC, it just worked so I never bothered. The corresponding route in there (localhost/root/home/order) works fine if I enter it in a browser, but with the kohana app it doesn't... So it looks to me like your suggestion produces the correct route, but it does'nt work. That's what confuses me.

Comment: Since your answer seems to give me the proper route, I accept this as the answer and continue the problem with why the route still doesn't work in another question. Thanks.